# Why would i create an instance of class inside the class itself?

Tags: php, oop

actually, i have got a database connection class from Github, where the author, tended to instantiate an instance inside the class definition, but i didn't understand why i would do so, please try to simplify, and here is the code

```
<?php

class Database {

private $_connection;
private static $_instance; //The single instance
private $_host = "HOSTt";
private $_username = "USERNAME";
private $_password = "PASSWORd";
private $_database = "DATABASE";

/*
Get an instance of the Database
@return Instance
*/
public static function getInstance() {
    if(!self::$_instance) { // If no instance then make one
        self::$_instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$_instance;
}
//then the rest of the class
?>
```

Comment: Yes, it's a Singleton, the static $_instance, because it's defined as static, it preserves its value for different class instances. Regarding usage, just make sure that you always call Database::getInstance()->whateverMethodYouWant().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design pattern called singleton. It is used when you want at most one instance of this class.

Comment: It's also considered an anti-pattern these days, because it's way too easy to abuse and is rarely (i'd argue never) a good solution to the problem.

Comment: Thank you, now i know it is related to the singleton pattern, i will read more